# Applying Mapping Function on DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have just started using databricks/pyspark. Im using python/spark 2.1. I have uploaded data to a table. This table is a single column full of strings. I wish to apply a mapping function to each element in the column. I load the table into a dataframe:

```
df = spark.table("mynewtable")
```

The only way I could see was others saying was to convert it to RDD to apply the mapping function and then back to dataframe to show the data. But this throws up job aborted stage failure:

```
df2 = df.select("_c0").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.append("anything")).toDF()
```

All i want to do is just apply any sort of map function to my data in the table.
For example append something to each string in the column, or perform a split on a char, and then put that back into a dataframe so i can .show() or display it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You cannot:

- Use `flatMap` because it will flatten the `Row`
- You cannot use `append` because:

  - `tuple` or `Row` have no append method
  - `append` (if present on collection) is executed for side effects and returns `None`

I would use `withColumn`:

```
df.withColumn("foo", lit("anything"))
```

but `map` should work as well:

```
df.select("_c0").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x + ("anything", )).toDF()
```

**Edit** (given the comment):

You probably want an `udf`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def iplookup(s):
    return ... # Some lookup logic

iplookup_udf = udf(iplookup)

df.withColumn("foo", iplookup_udf("c0"))
```

Default return type is `StringType`, so if you want something else you should adjust it.

Comment: I have a follow-up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295160/pyspark-mapping-variables-from-different-dataframes @Alper t. Turker

Comment: which one gives the best performance in pyspark udf or rdd processing ?