# collaborating address columns from multiple tables into one column (3million rows)

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table that looks like this

| common_id | table1_address | table2_address | table3_address | table4_address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | null | null | stack building12 | null |
| 157 | 123road street12 | 123road street 33 | 123road street 44 | 123road street 45 |
| 158 | wolf building 451-2 | 451-2 building wolf | wolf building 451-2 | null |
| 163 | null | sweet rd. 254-11 | null | -- |

I have about 3 million rows that contains address information from different tables with common_id. I joined 4 tables and made it into one table. I want to make the address rows into one address row that looks like this.

| common_id | collaborated_address |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | stack building12 |
| 157 | 123road street12 |
| 158 | wolf building 451-2 |
| 163 | sweet rd. 254-11 |

I tried to do this by using pandas, **but it takes too long** so I want to do this by using ***spark sql or pyspark functions*.**

Conditions:

1. when collaborated, it should collect only the ones that are not null or not "--"
2. like row common_id 158, it should collect addresses that are mostly the same. In this case, "wolf building 451-2" is in table1_address column and table3_address.
3. if all column contains address but has slightly different address like row common_id 157, then it should collect random address.

Answer (score 0):

There are few approaches:

1. Using rdd with map function.
   https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.map.html

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
data = [('James','Smith','M',30),('Anna','Rose','F',41),
   ('Robert','Williams','M',62),
 ]
columns = ["firstname","lastname","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)
df.show()
# Output:
+---------+--------+------+------+
|firstname|lastname|gender|salary|
+---------+--------+------+------+
|    James|   Smith|     M|    30|
|     Anna|    Rose|     F|    41|
|   Robert|Williams|     M|    62|
+---------+--------+------+------+

def isMale(row):
    # Basic Function, replace your address matching logic here.
     if row['gender']=="M":
             return True
     return False

rdd=df.rdd.map(lambda x:isMale(x))
actual_df=rdd.map(lambda x: Row(x)).toDF()
actual_df
DataFrame[_1: boolean]
actual_df.show()
+-----+
|   _1|
+-----+
| true|
|false|
| true|
+-----+
```

2. Using map with dataframes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45404691/2986344